# When setting view to GONE it slips under SurfaceView on Sony Xperia

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surface view and a custom view (gallery) above it (see layout snippet).
Initially gallery is `View.GONE`. When certain button it is set to `View.VISIBLE`.

This approach works on most devices. Not on Sony Xperia (4.0.4). All views (there are more) who's visibility were set to GONE just slips under `SurfaceView`.

I'm struggling with this 2 days already.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    ...

    <com.apps.activities.photo.TakenPhotosGallery
        android:id="@+id/take_photos_mini_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

    ...
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough to set background to transparent for `SurfaceView` to fix the issue.